# I want to change the margin with animation to move this in my Android app. How to do it?

Tags: android, android-studio

Here is the Android Studio code for my android app:

```
    FrameLayout root = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
    ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    img.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
     //..load something inside the ImageView, we just set the background color

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(20, 20);
    params.leftMargin=Math.round(deltaX);
    params.topMargin=Math.round(deltaY);
    root.addView(img,params);
    //...
```

I want to move this with animation when the value of topMargin and leftMargin change.

Answer (score 0):

You can change to `Padding`

```
    FrameLayout root = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
    ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(20, 20);
    img.setLayoutParams(params);
    img.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    //..load something inside the ImageView, we just set the background color

    root.setPadding(deltaX, deltaX, 0, 0);
    root.addView(img);
```

Then, you can use `Property Animation`

```
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(root, "translationX", 0, 1000).start();
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(root, "translationY", 0, 1000).start();
```

or

```
    root.animate().translationY(100);
```

Comment: Thank you.. you answer helps me a lot. Can you tell me please how to make the animation smooth? I think it can be done using the those class built for animation.

Comment: @FaruqueAhamedMollick Updated.